# Video not autoplaying on some mobile browsers in React

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

I have been trying to figure out how to fix my video element when viewing my site on all phone devices. I have tried using div dangerouslySetInnerHTML and it has somewhat fixed the issue. It seems to be working on some devices like my iPhone 11 and iPhone 12 on safari, chrome, and firefox. It does not work on my friend's iPhone 12 safari though. Why would this be happening and what method is there to make sure it works across all devices and browsers.

https://www.ollinsalon.com/

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `
                    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline >
                        <source src='https://ollin-salon.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/moon.mp4'></source>
                    </video>
                `
            }}/>
```

Comment: If it’s a short video you can try to convert it into .gif so it may work on all devices (https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif)

Comment: that's what I was thinking. I actually had her clear her cache which fixed it. But I may end up doing that just to make sure. I think old phones may have trouble autoplaying videos.